# Finding a fit for left-skewed continuous data

Tags: distributions, mixed-model, data-transformation, residuals, diagnostic

I am looking at various plant community traits and how they relate to a number of environmental variables in a woodland. I am using mixed models as some samples come from the same woodlands so I'm modelling 'woodland site' as a random effect.

My response variable is a measure of a plant functional trait scored on a scale between 2 and 7 (any value up to several decimal places between 2 and 7) so I think this makes it continuous but bounded. I have over a 1000 samples. The mean of the response is 5.37 and the median is 5.61.

The distribution of the response is left skewed with very few values less than 5 but many values between 5-7 (histogram below). I think this is because higher values of this trait are more common generally and will have been sampled more. This variable can also be affected by many different stochastic events - regardless of it's relationship to other site factors.

[image]

I am running an lmer with just over half a dozen explanatory variables, which are continuous, count and categorical. The best model fit I have come up with is detailed by the diagnostic plots below. I think the patterns in the residuals look dodgy and have tried several approaches to rectifying it with little change. I have tried a log-transformation and a square-root transformation of the response. I have also added polynomial terms for the significant predictor variables, but none of these has improved the residuals plot. What else can I try? Are these plots actually OK given the constraints of the data? Or am I just using the wrong type of model altogether?

Residual plot - this was barely changed by transforming the response/adding quadratic terms.
[image]

qqplot

[image]

Comment: I've seen something like this in other models that use categorical predictors with outcome distributions that have a real skew. Have you looked at a residuals plot with only continuous predictors?

Comment: Use semiparametric (ordinal) regression for continuous Y: https://fharrell.com/post/rpo